# I uploaded a video to github readme, but where can i find the video

Tags: github

After watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3Cytlicv8Y this video, I found out that i can upload videos to readme with just Drag and drop.

After uploading, i got a link like "https://github.com/UserName/RepositoryName/assets/hashcode

but i cannot find assets folder in my repository.
Where is the video I uploaded? And if I lose the link, how do I find it again

that video says videos which is uploaded can be found in assets folder. but i cannot find assets folder in my repository.

Comment: Could be that the link https://github.com/UserName/RepositoryName/assets/hashcode is the path to the file in the repo?

Comment: @Gastón Schabas
Yes, when i upload video or something in readme with Drag & Drop, i got like like that "https://github.com/UserName/RepositoryName/assets/~~~hashcode~~~" but i wanna know where can i the video, where is the video

Comment: If you browse the github repo, can't you see it inside that path named as a `hashcode`? Try to show more details or even screenshots